# Is a VirtualBox image just an image of a /* files?

Tags: virtualbox, iso, images

If I make an iso of all the files in / as an iso, will I be able to convert that to a usable VirtualBox image?

I've been looking around for documentation, and have been able to find no documentation that explicitly say this. Links to reliable documentation is a plus, so I can learn for myself.

Comment: Are you asking how to do a physical to virtual migration of a linux box to virtual box?

Comment: Apparently so [[157104](http://serverfault.com/questions/157104/how-do-i-export-my-web-hosts-vps-filesystem-to-an-image-to-load-locally-in-a-v)]. What is it with noobs not following up on their own questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.  A VirtualBox image is a specially formatted image of a hard drive (either a bit-for-bit copy or one designed to achieve the same results in less space), not simply a collection of files pulled from a running system.

To produce such an image from an existing system you can use something like VMWare Converter.  http://blog.subaquatic.net/archives/virtualbox-p2v-success/ has more details (this deals with a Windows migration, but the process is substantially equivalent for *NIX hosts)