# How to migrate physical Debian installation into VirtualBox image

Tags: debian, virtualization, virtualbox

I have a physical (not virtualized) 32Bit Debian server I'd like to mirror as VirtualBox image. I seem unable to find tools like vmware-converter to do the trick.

So: what tools can I use? Or, can you point me to a howto document?

Edit:
After I posted my question, I found this: [Creating a virtual machine in VirtualBox from a physical one](https://serverfault.com/questions/33603/creating-a-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox-from-a-physical-one)

Still, I hoped for a tool...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) to get a copy of a (running) physical machine. The resulting image can be user natively by current VirtualBox releases.

Answer (score 7):

One way should be just to take image of your server with the good old dd:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/somewhere/with/lots/of/diskspace/serverimage.dd bs=1M
```

(assuming your server HD is /dev/sda)

And then convert the dd image to VirtualBox image using VBoxManage:

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw serverimage.dd serverimage.vdi
```

Then just add that as your virtual server HD from VirtualBox GUI and you should be all set.

Comment: On Windows: `"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" convertfromraw machine.dd machine.vdi`

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few ways to approach this, but one way could be:

- Create a VM with USB support & appropriately sized (and like/physical equivalent - IDE, SCSI, etc.) VM storage
- Transfer physical disk onto USB case/enclosure
- Boot VM with a bootable CD-based partition manager (maybe something with gParted, Acronis, etc.) with USB drive attached
- Copy partitions from "USB drive" onto VM storage