# convert vmware snapshot to vdi

Tags: virtualbox, snapshot, vmware-vmdk

I found plenty of documentation on how to convert a .vmdk file to a .vdi (VirtualBox) file. But they all assume you don't use snapshots. -- Is there a way to convert the vmdk snapshots too?

Answer (score 2):

I believe they might be using incompatible "differentiating" algo and storage format. You probably will have to examine official specification, or google for software that does it.

Also, as an ugly hack, u can discard/merge these snaps, and use several v-machines (or just backup it as a file, if your snaps just have some initial state saved)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to convert it?  VirtualBox will read vmdk files just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Currently virtual conversion tools will not convert snapshots, AFAIK. Remove snapshots and use vmdk directly or convert to vdi. Or clone using livecd disk or network cloning tools. The cloned disk will not have snapshots, but you won't have to remove the snapshots from your existing system.

Cloning tips here -
[How to increase the size of a VirtualBox Disk Image](https://serverfault.com/questions/2678/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-virtualbox-disk-image)